# jQuery - After scrolling to the top a div, I want to animate/restore a fixed div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed div moving along my document as I scroll up/down. I am looking for the means to animate this div as soon as I reach the top of a specific div on my document. The animation will be very simple css, consisting of changing its background color to another color; if and only if I scroll to the top of the specific div.

For a more practical reference: if I am above div A, my fixed div (div B)'s background color will be blue; once I scroll to the top of A, B's background color will be red. If I scroll to the top of A again, the background color of the fixed div will change to blue... and so on.

My jQuery code:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var swapColors = 1; // used to swap colors on the #fixedDiv

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if(swapColors) {
                --swapColors;
                if ($(window).scrollTop >= $('#landmarkDiv').offset().top) {
                    $('#fixedDiv').animate(
                        {
                        "background-color": "red"
                        }, "slow"
                    );
                }                   
            }
            else {
                ++swapColors;
                if ($(window).scrollTop < $('#landmarkDiv').offset().top) {
                    $('#fixedDiv').animate(
                        {
                        "background-color": "blue"
                        }, "slow"
                    );
                }  
            }
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's just many issues in your code.

You have an extra curly brackets in there. function(query) not required. works without it.

$(window).scrollTop needs a () at the end.

```
$(window).scrollTop();
```

.animate() function on a backgroundcolor has issues. You may need extra library to let jquery to do animation on color. Instead we can use css() and webkit-transition.

HTML:

```
</div>
<div id="testDiv">
    Test div
</div>
<div id="landmarkDiv">
    landmark
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#fixedDiv {
        position: fixed;
        top:0px;
        width: 100%;
        height:50px;
        background-color: #456456; 
        -webkit-transition: all 3s;
    }

    #testDiv {
        width: 600px;
        height: 1200px;
    }

    #landmarkDiv {
        width: 100%;
        height: 1000px;
    }
```

JQuery:

$(document).ready(function() {
    var swapColors = 1; // used to swap colors on the #fixedDiv

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var windowScrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(swapColors) {
        --swapColors;
        if (windowScrollPosition >= $('#landmarkDiv').offset().top) {
            $('#fixedDiv').css('backgroundColor', "red");
            console.log(windowScrollPosition, 'more');
        }                   
    }
    else {
        ++swapColors;
        if (windowScrollPosition < $('#landmarkDiv').offset().top) {
            $('#fixedDiv').css('backgroundColor', "blue");
            console.log(windowScrollPosition, 'less');
        }  
    }
});
```

});

Working test here:
[www.gdiction.com/scroll](http://gdiction.com/scroll)

Comment: Thank you for this very good answer, not only did it answer my question but it highlighted a lot of other things that I can learn from! I took this code and implemented it on top of what I am doing and it worked great.